# Is there a way to get the registered function names in php nusoap library?

Tags: php, soap, nusoap

I want to get the registered function names in an array. 
Is it possible?
It will be great if I can get that array from my client side code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is what you mean, but try:

```
print_r(get_defined_functions());
```

This will give you something like this:

```
Array
(
    [internal] => Array
        (
            [0] => zend_version
            [1] => func_num_args
            [2] => func_get_arg
            [3] => func_get_args
            [4] => strlen
            [5] => strcmp
            ...
            [1274] => xmlwriter_write_dtd_attlist
            [1275] => xmlwriter_output_memory
            [1276] => xmlwriter_flush
        )

    [user] => Array
        (
            [0] => foo
            [1] => bar
        )
)
```

The user subarray is the one you're looking for.